# Can I connect to eduroam using a non-touch Kindle?

Tags: kindle, wifi

Eduroam is a network that allows members of universities or research institutes to use wifi in other universities or research institutes without having to register for a guest account. This utilizes WPA2 Enterprise authentification.

Connecting to WPA2 Enterprise networks was not supported on older Kindles (e.g. hacks needed to be used for Kindle 3 devices). With recent Kindles it seems to be [possible](https://tribut.de/blog/amazon-kindle-and-eduroam/) at least for Kindle Touch and Kindle Paperwhite.

Is is also possible out of the box for "basic" Kindles with physical buttons (K4NT)?
If not: Are hacks needed and available?

Comment: Just for the record, the Kindle 2 is WhisperNet only — no wifi. I mention this because of course the K2 is one of the Kindles with a keyboard that precedes the Kindle Touch.

Answer (score 2):

You need to jailbreak your Kindle 4 NT and have usbnetwork installed. The following hack worked for me:

http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Kindle4NTHacking#Connecting_to_eduroam

Comment: Answers on this site will be better received if you were to summarize the important steps from the link rather than provided a link-only answer. This protects against dead links in the future and provides more value to users of the site.

Comment: I am not a fan of reposts and I respect the authors intellectual property. I will reconstruct the proposed algorithm here to avoid a possible dead link. However, down voting creates the false impression that the suggested solution is simply wrong or inaccurate.

Comment: That is all I meant. Linking to the original author's post is ideal, so long as you provide protection against a future dead link (otherwise this post loses all of its value). As for the downvoting, I agree with you. I was just informing you of why you were likely downvoted, but it was not me that actually gave you the downvote. I would prefer that people only downvote incorrect answers or at least provide a reason why they gave a downvote. Unfortunately that is not enforced in the Stack Exchange community.